# Getting a warning when I use a class within a class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Course{

  public:
  string name;
  int pars[];
  Course();

};

class Runs{

  public:
  Course course; <- Error
  int scores[];
  Runs();

};
```

I am trying to use the classes to read lines from a badly formatted file. Why can't I use a class within a class?

Comment: Why do you think you can't? What errors does the compiler give you? Hint: double check how you are defining your arrays.

Comment: You have asked about the *last* error message emitted by your compiler related to instantiating your classes.   A preceding error message is that `int pars[];` is invalid within a class definition, so means the definition of class `Course` is invalid.    The error message you have asked about is a consequence of that preceding error.   Arrays without dimensions are not allowed in C++.  A subsequent error is that `int scores[]` in `main()` is also invalid.    You can't cherry-pick error messages if you wish to solve problems.

Comment: `int pars[];` probably should be `vector<int> pars;`.  Also, `int scores[];` probably should be `vector<int> scores;`.

Comment: Error messages should be copied (as text) into questions so that future readers with the same issue have a better chance of finding the question and its answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int pars[];
```

This is not a valid C++ class member declaration. In standard C++ the sizes of all arrays ***must be defined at compile-time*** as a constant, fixed size.

Your compiler implements a non-standard C++ language extension that allows this class member declaration in order to use it in a particular way. However you cannot use that class, any more, as a member of another class, due to the technical way in which this non-standard C++ language extension works.

You will need to remove this class member. Perhaps use a `std::vector` in its place, which is basically an array whose size can be changed at runtime. See your C++ textbook for a more complete discussion of vectors, how they work, and how to use them.